# GoPro video is sped up!

Tags: camera

I'm using a GoPro 9 set to "*Looping*", "*Superview*" mounted in a protective case on top of my cycle helmet. The video however is so speeded up as to be unusable as a cycle cam. I believe there was at least one firmware update while I was on the bench with an injury.

I turn it on using the "***Quick Record***" feature by pressing the "*Record*" button on top in lieu of the "*Power*" button on the side. This both powers the camera on and starts recording with a single button press.

Googling the problem only returned [THIS](https://community.gopro.com/t5/GoPro-Apps-for-Mobile/Video-is-sped-up/m-p/561029#/M18918), but I've checked the settings and neither "*Time Lapse*" or any other mode has been changed.

How do I record video at normal speed?!?!?

Comment: Would the https://video.stackexchange.com/ would be more suitable?

Comment: Not really: this was really a problem borne of its use as a cycle cam mounted on my helmet. Fumbling around, failing to get immediate feedback the cam was activated combined to give me the issue. If I was merely holding it in my hand while looking at it, probably wouldn’t have made the boo-boo that I did. So I could see other cyclists having the same issue for this particular use-case. But must admit, didn’t occur to mr to post it there. Much obliged for the feedback- much appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is programming on a boat.

Comment: @Swifty GoPro's are probably the most popular cycle cam in use, so I felt other's were likely to bump into the same issue. Was only trying to save  others cyclists the time & effort of solving the same problem.  As you know Swifty I'm very democratic and take on board the views of others in the community.  If they decide that the question is inappropriate, then one is only left to be gracious and accept the verdict. Your feedback is always much appreciated-

Comment: @Swifty does it really count as question, when it's answered by the author in a minute after posting it?

Comment: @ojs: self-answered questions are fine. Encouraged, even. If they can be on-topic. This question is clearly off-topic, and it boggles my mind why it remains here. Is any question phrased as "do X **on a bicycle**" automatically allowed here now? I shouldn't think it would be, but that's exactly what this question is. It has **nothing** more to do with bicycles than, say, me asking whether I should use an Android phone or an iPhone  to run Google Maps while I'm cycling.

Comment: @ojs: you asked _"does it really count as question, when it's answered by the author in a minute after posting it?"_ I responded to _that_ question. Even when self-answering, one must follow the usual guidelines. But the fact that in your view _"the answer is almost always a rant"_, has nothing to do with whether self-answering is _in general_ acceptable. It clearly is, which is the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @PeterDuniho what I was after was whether it was a real question that the person had, or did they just read a detail in user manual an decided to invent a question about it to boost their scores.

Comment: @ojs: _"did they just read a detail in user manual an decided to invent a question about it to boost their scores"_ -- We would do well to avoid trying to guess the _motive_ a person has for their activity on a Stack Exchange site. It's true that the reputation system tends toward "gamified" behaviors, and _some_ people do things solely to try to increase their score. But that could be said of anyone asking a question or answering one (you get points for both). We can give the author here the benefit of the doubt in regard to motivation, even as we question whether the Q&A belong here at all.

Comment: @ojs I post things that I couldn't myself find answers to and feel are problems other forum users are likely to bump into. My ONLY intention is to save wasted time with many troubleshooting the same problem unnecessarily ad infinitum, but for somebody taking a moment to document the solution; accumulating points is not my goal. As I noted in the question I was unable to locate the solution in even the GoPro forums. Many cyclists use a GoPro as a cycle cam, and 10 found this answer helpful. I feel that is (some) validation of the question's relevance. I did accept Swifty's concerns though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A potential firmware update being the cause was a red herring; no fault was introduced via any FW update. Nor were any settings incorrect. The "***fault***" was in fact a "***feature***":

### Answer:

**If you long-press the "***Record***" button on top of the GoPro for 3 seconds it initiates "***Time Lapse***" with "Quick Capture" and overrides the manual settings**.

This is why you clearly see "Time Lapse" is active in the videos, but you ***can't see*** any evidence of it when you check your settings: Long-Pressing only sets it ***non-persistently*** making it difficult to troubleshoot.

Since the GoPro is in a protective case, when reaching up on top of my helmet activating it with gloves on, I was mashing the button down for too long because the camera doesn't give immediate feedback that it's actually on. Be warned...

That devil was buried in the "***Using Quick Capture***" section of the GoPro Manual on page 44 of the GoPro 9 PDF User Guide.

Comment: I use a GoPro 9 when spear fishing. I get the same issue. All the videos are sped up. I lost some good footage to this stupid feature. I must long press it once but then all videos after are sped-up as well even from single press of the record button.